# Closed Area 51 proposals show more to anonymous users than when logged in

Tags: support, area-51, login, user-accounts, users

This is what the [What If proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127528/what-if) looks like when logged in:

[image: Area 51 logged in]

That's fine, I can live with that.

However, this is when **not** logged in:

[image: Area 51 not logged in]

Same page, same browser (Firefox 107 x64). One in a normal window, the other one using private browsing.

Now, regardless of whether the proposal is closed, removed or both, I don't expect an anonymous user to be shown more than a logged in one. The other way around, I could understand. But I see no valid use case for the current situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are (at least) two separate closed What If? Area 51 (Stack Exchange site) proposals: A [new one from 2022](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127528/what-if), and [an old one from 2016](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/95463/what-if). The 2016 proposal is deleted, and the 2022 proposal is not. It looks like you got your links mixed up slightly, and were viewing one link regularly and a different one in incognito.

The old one was linked in a post on Area 51 Discussions about why the 2016 What If? proposal was closed. A new Discussions post about the 2022 proposal was closed as a duplicate of the 2016 discussion, which is probably how you landed on the old proposal link. Since the URLs looks practically identical aside from the numeric ID, it's an easy mistake to make.